# NestJS - How do I expose param in Swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I am using NestJs. I have this controller:

```
@Get(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get action by id' }) 
  findById(@Param('id') id: string, @Query() query?: SelectQuery & PopulateQuery): Promise<Action> {
    return this.actionService.findById(id, query);
  }
```

When I open the page in Swagger, it says there are no parameters available.

In the Swagger, how can I make the param 'id' as an input box, so I can use it in the Swagger (browser)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Moments after I posted the question, I found the answer.
It is simple. Just add the following.

```
@ApiParam({
    name: 'id',
    description: 'Gets the Action id',
  })
```

Comment: added where please?

Comment: @Suleiman AbdulMajeed 

It should be added as a decorator to your controller method (in this case, `findById`).